# How to reference another put action method in the same controller file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

my project involves two models - User and Request - where a user can create a food delivery request and attach tokens as rewards, while another user can help to deliver and claim the tokens.

In the same controller.js file, I have a method *transferTokens* (put action) and another *delete* (delete action) method. My question is how can I call the delete method at the end of transferTokens? I am separating both methods as there would be instances where user can delete his own requests without any token transfer (that is, before any other user agrees to deliver that request).

The code is:

```
let controller = {
  transferTokens: (req, res) => {
   // Request.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }) 
   // ...
   // User.findOneAndUpdate...
   // ... add tokens to user-helper
   // controller.delete();
  },
  delete: (req,res) => {
   // Request.findOneAndRemove
   // ...
   // res.redirect('/home');
  }
}
module.exports = controller
```

So, this is definitely wrong. The request does get deleted, but the error message is res is undefined. Usually, the user clicks on the delete button in the view, but in this case, the user-helper clicks on the 'claim tokens' button which initiates the transferTokens put action.

edit: I managed to find a way out using app.set

`app.set('res', res);
controller.delete(req, app.get('res'))`

Comment: You may just create function `delete` that would be delete specific record adn then call it in `transferToken` as well as in `delete` controller functions

Comment: I have done that, but the delete function is not getting the 'req' and 'res' params through the usual way (from a form) but by being called by another controller action

Answer (score 0):

// please specify more clearly

```
transferTokens :function(req,res){
   var model = req.allParams();

   Request
   .findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
   .exec(function(err,request){
      if(err) err

      if(request){

        //in this you should match any condition with your another table
        // so supose we have User table
        var userFilter ={
         id :request.id(as ur key)
        }

        User
        .findOne(userFilter)
        .exec(function(err,user){
           if(err) return err

           if(user){
             user.destroy(function (err) {
                                if (err) return res.toJson(false, [], "Error.");

                                return res.toJson(true, user, "Sucess.");
                            });
           }
        })

      }
      else{
        return  empty
      }
   })
}
```